# Pull the image path from a database and display the image

Tags: php, html

What I'm trying to do is to have the user search for a product and upon searching for it, bring back an image. I want this to happen by pulling the image's path from the database and have it be part of the "" path. I've seen a few tutorials and similar questions online but all of them require the user to first upload the image (which I don't want to happen).

So the query definitely works, it pulls all text data out which can be seen when I run it. I'm lead to believe it's the path then, but I'm not sure why it's not working. I have the  and it takes the "img/ImageName path (which is pulled directly from the database. I've even played around with it, having the "img/" appear as part of the PHP (as a string). However, whenever I perform the query the only thing that shows up where the image should be is the alt "could not be found" icon.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```html
<form action="searchDB.php" method="GET" id="searchForm">
    <p>Search for the product you want!</p>
    <input type="text" name="product" id="product" placeholder="Product...">
    <br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbase);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
   echo "Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error;
}

if(empty($_GET['product']) ){
   die('please input a search!');
} else {

$product = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['product']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product = '$product'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


?>

<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  //output each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){#
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['product'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['brand'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['cost'].'</td>';

   /*This is the path here, it pulls the image path from the database 
   ("img/Image-Name") and puts it in a "src" attribute*/
    echo '<td>' ."<img src=/'" .$row['image']."' />" .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['specification'].'</td>';    
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
} else {
   echo "Sorry, we could not find any products relating to your search.";
}

}


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
echo '<td>' ."<img src=/'" .$row['image']."' />" .'</td>';
```

to either this

```
echo '<td>' ."<img src='" .$row['image']."' />" .'</td>';
```

or to this

```
echo '<td>' ."<img src='/" .$row['image']."' />" .'</td>';
```

depending on, whether you really need the forward slash in the beginning of the path or not.

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds ;)

Comment: Was typing the same thing when I saw two answers pop up XD

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. Managed to get it working with that and double checking the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

This will yield in invalid (or semi-valid, because HTML is very forgiveable) HTML:

```
echo '<td>' ."<img src=/'" .$row['image']."' />" .'</td>';
//                      ^ Note the open-quote is AFTER the /
// So this will look like
<img src=/'img/product.jpg' />
```

Instead of what you probably want

```
<img src='/img/product.jpg' />
```

Comment: Thanks man. I upvoted it but because my reputation is so low it doesn't show it. I appreciate your help.